# Using sql-sqlite via TRAMP

Tags: tramp, sql-mode

I want to use sql-sqlite on a remote database file via TRAMP. According to [this website](http://gregorygrubbs.com/wordpress/emacs-power-remote-servers-and-shell-commands/) it should be possible, but I cannot get it to work.

I visit the remote directory with Dired and then invoke sql-sqlite:

```
C-x d /user@host:/directory
M-x sql-sqlite /scp:user@host:/directory/test.db
```

As expected, this opens an `*SQL*` buffer with an sqlite prompt. Entering any SQL statements or SQLite commands, however, results in this:

```
Error: unable to open database "/scp:user@host:/directory/test.db": unable to open database file

Process SQL exited abnormally with code 1
```

I am using Emacs 25.1 with `emacs -Q` (the other two versions I have access to, 24.3 and 24.5, behave identically).

Answer (score 5):

After some experimentation and a bit of digging around in the source code, I recognized what went wrong. Running `M-x sql-sqlite` from the remote Dired buffer starts a remote SQLite process and that process needs to be provided with the absolute path to the database file *on the remote machine*. So instead of this:

```
C-x d /user@host:/directory
M-x sql-sqlite RET /scp:user@host:/directory/test.db
```

I need to to this:

```
C-x d /user@host:/directory
M-x sql-sqlite RET /directory/test.db
```

Comment: You seem to have created multiple accounts, see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts